# Proof that $\frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|}$ has fixed points.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems, fixed-points

> Let $A\in \operatorname{Mat}_{2\times 2}(\Bbb{R})$ with eigenvalues $\lambda\in (1,\infty)$ and $\mu\in (0,1)$. Define $$T:S^1\rightarrow S^1;~~x\mapsto \frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|}$$
> I need to show that $T$ has 4 fixed points.

My idea was the following. Since $\mu, \lambda$ are eigenvalues there exists, $x,y\neq 0$ such that $Ax=\mu x$ and $Ay=\lambda y$.Then I claim that $x,y$ are fixed points:$$Tx=\frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|}=\frac{\mu x}{\|\mu x\|}=\operatorname{sign}(\mu)\frac{x}{\|x\|}=\frac{x}{\|x\|}=x$$ similarly one can show that $Ty=y$. But then I don't see where the other two fixed points should come from?

Comment: In your two given fixed points, make sure that $x$ and $y$ are unit eigenvectors, so they are in $S^1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other two fixed points are $-x$ and $-y$, when $x$ and $y$ lie on $S^1$ (they can always be chosen to lie on $S^1$ since eigenvectors can be scaled), since $S^1$ is invariant under negation:
$$-x\mapsto\frac{-Ax}{\|Ax\|}=\frac{-\mu x}{\|\mu x\|}=-x$$
Note that the problem statement still holds, and this proof still works (if "$4$ fixed points" means *at least* $4$), as long as $A$ has linearly independent eigenvectors and positive eigenvalues.

Comment: My question is how can i guarantee that $x,y$ lie on $S^1$

Comment: @Summerday In full glory, an eigenvalue is not just associated with an eigenvector but an _eigenspace_ of at least one dimension. Therefore an eigenvector can always be chosen to have unit length.

Comment: Ah okey but you now tell me that the fixed points are $x,y,-x,-y$ but in the answer below there is a different statement. What is now correct?

Comment: @Summerday In this answer I already assume that $|x|=|y|=1$, _without loss of generality_. The other answer is merely making this explicit.

Comment: Ah I see perfect thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your two eigenvectors $x,y$ are only assumed to be non-zero, so they are not in $S^1.$

A point $z\in S^1$ is fixed by $T$ iff $Az=\|Az\|z,$ i.e. iff $z$ is an eigenvector for some positive eigenvalue.

Therefore, the fixed points of $T$ are exactly the *unit* eigenvectors of $A,$ i.e. the $4$ vectors
$$\frac x{\|x\|},\;-\frac x{\|x\|},\;
\frac y{\|y\|},\;-\frac y{\|y\|}.$$

Comment: Would you do it by contradictio, so assume $z\in S^1$ is another fixed point, i.e. $Tz=\frac{Az}{\|Az\|}=z$. But then I don't see how to continue